# "Entry has already been added" - Two Separate App Pools

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, application-pool

I am creating a test version of an existing production site. A virtual web service application exists inside the site - and the two web configs have the same connection string.

There are no "clear" tags in the production web configs and the site and the web service co-exist merrily on two separate app pools.

On the test site however, every time I browse to the webservice URL I receive the Configuration Error "The entry 'ConnectionString' has already been added."

The test site and corresponding virtual application use their own separate app pools. Any ideas?

Thanks
Jim

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Web.config inheritance happens even between different appPools.
If you want to stop this behavior, you should add the attribute `enableConfigurationOverride="false"` to your appPool in the  applicationHost.config file (located in %WINDIR%\System32\inetsrv\Config and %WINDIR%\SysWOW64\inetsrv\config) as in the following example:

```
<add name="MyAppPool" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" enableConfigurationOverride="false">
    <processModel identityType="NetworkService" />
</add>
```

Matteo

Comment: This is not working for me on IIS7.5 (I am assuming I should add this attribute on child App's AppPool)

Comment: I don't remember and currently I don't have that environment anymore, anyway I'd try adding it to the parent appPool (or both of them)

Comment: Worked well for me, added on the child app pool. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is related that they are one site inside the other. Like a Website with a Virtual Directory inside.

In this case... the Virtual Directory web.config is "inheriting" the parent web.config

Here you can see details of how to solve this: [How to stop inheritance of <configSections>in Web.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572326/how-to-stop-inheritance-of-configsectionsin-web-config)

Other options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/367372/7720

If the problem is in other parts of your web.config (not in the sections) you can just wrap the conflicting part with `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">`.

Other option could be let the webservice grab the connection from the website.

Comment: Thanks - but does this apply if the virtual application is running in a different app pool? (Configured at the folder level of IIS)

Comment: Not really sure... In my case, I THINK I HAVE different App Pools in parent and child, but as it is shared hosting not easy way to know.

Comment: OK.. Thanks. I've opted for changing the connection string.